# #1054 - Unknown column 'countf' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I don't know where is the error please help me :)

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,users.*,
    (SELECT msg_text FROM message_private p 
     WHERE p.group_id=a.group_id ORDER BY occured_at DESC LIMIT 1) as message,
    (SELECT COUNT(f.profile_id) as countf from message_view f WHERE f.profile_id = 'sN07X2' AND f.id_group = b.group_id) 
FROM message_group a
JOIN message_group b ON a.group_id=b.group_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.profile_id = b.profile_id
WHERE a.profile_id = 'sN07X2'
AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id AND countf != 0 ORDER BY a.message_group_id DESC LIMIT 9
```

Comment: please provide error message...

Comment: @DanielRobertus the error message is the title..

Comment: You cannot use an alias from the select in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Daanvn: no. numbers don't need single quotes, only character literals ("strings") need them.

Comment: you need grouping before count and then you can add some condition like having `COUNT(f.profile_id)<>0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting to reference a column alias from the SELECT list in your WHERE clause.  You might want to look at using a JOIN with the `message_view` table to get the result, then you can filter on the alias:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,users.*,
    (SELECT msg_text 
    FROM message_private p 
    WHERE p.group_id=a.group_id 
    ORDER BY occured_at DESC LIMIT 1) as message,
    f.countf 
FROM message_group a
INNER JOIN message_group b ON a.group_id=b.group_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.profile_id = b.profile_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(profile_id) countf, id_group
    FROM message_view
    WHERE profile_id = 'sN07X2'
    GROUP BY id_group
) f
  on f.id_group = b.group_id
WHERE a.profile_id = 'sN07X2'
    AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id 
    AND countf != 0 
ORDER BY a.message_group_id DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

Comment: thank you so much, but appaers this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a.profile_id = 'sN07X2' AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id AND co' at line 17

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining `countf` in a subquery *and* trying to reference it in a `where` clause.  Instead, you need to have the `as countf` in the outer select and use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,users.*,
    (SELECT msg_text FROM message_private p 
     WHERE p.group_id=a.group_id ORDER BY occured_at DESC LIMIT 1) as message,
    (SELECT COUNT(f.profile_id) as countf from message_view f WHERE f.profile_id = 'sN07X2' AND f.id_group = b.group_id
   ) as countf
FROM message_group a
JOIN message_group b ON a.group_id=b.group_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.profile_id = b.profile_id
WHERE a.profile_id = 'sN07X2'
AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id
having countf <> 0
ORDER BY a.message_group_id DESC LIMIT 9
```